# SQL - Trying to find the SUM of a SUM from an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sum

I'm trying to find the total amount sold in these tables, by first multiplying the quantities with item price then finding the sum of all the items in the columns from the total of those items(ItemPrice * quantities). I am very new to this if it isn't painfully obvious.

```
SELECT SUM(dbo.OrderLineItems.Quantity * dbo.Products.ItemPrice) AS Total, dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate, SUM(Total) as SumTotal
FROM   dbo.OrderLineItems INNER JOIN
             dbo.Products ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID INNER JOIN
             dbo.OrdersTbl ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ItemID = dbo.OrdersTbl.ItemID
WHERE (dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-31 00:00:00')
GROUP BY dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate
```

The error i am receiving is: Invalid column name 'Total'.

Not sure why this isn't working? any advice would be appreciated.

It seems i dont have a high enough reputation to post pictures, hopefully this link will be sufficient. It is far from perfect since i created it, and have never done it before.

http://shuttergarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/ERD-Online-Store.jpg

Comment: What `RDBMS` are you using and which version?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you supply some sample data and the result you're expecting?

Comment: Is this Northwind or Adventureworks ? You cannot use an Alias in a select. To find out the reason, learn about the order in which SQL queries are evaluated. Alternately, you can use sub-queries.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: Please specify your problem (error, wrong result, ...) in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, i updated my post with more information. @RaghavPotluri Thank you again.

Comment: You don't want to use `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially on SQL Server.  Or with any continuous-range (non-integral) type, really.  Oh, does it have to be another _column_?  SQL Server since 2008 supports the `ROLLUP` clause, which would give the overall total as another **row** (with `OrderDate` as `null`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want a `ROLLUP`.  [The documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) of course has more information, but essentially it'll generate an additional rows with the total results for you.  I'd ten re-write your query like so:

```
SELECT dbo.OrdersTbl.orderDate, 
       SUM(dbo.OrderLineItems.quantity * dbo.Products.itemPrice) AS total
FROM   dbo.OrderLineItems 
INNER JOIN dbo.Products 
        ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID 
INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersTbl 
        ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ItemID = dbo.OrdersTbl.ItemID
           AND dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
           AND dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate < DATEADD(month, 1, '2013-05-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY ROLLUP (dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate)
```

(untested, because I have no set to back it against)
.. This should get results along these lines (note that this excludes days not present in your source!):

```
orderDate      total
'2013-05-01'   1
'2013-05-15'   100000
'2013-05-31'   13
(null)         100014
```

(As a side note, is it really `dbo.OrdersTbl.ItemID`?  I would have expected that to be `OrderId`)

Comment: This works way better than what i came up with, i still used a rollup and ended up with the same answer but it was a mess. And yes it was ItemID, admittedly i should have done it differently but by the time i realized the flaw (first database experience) i was already pretty deep into the project and the project was due this evening at midnight (PST). Later this quarter i will do a redesign for a second iteration of the project where i will fix some of my problems. Thank you for your insight and help with my problem. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderDate,
       SUM(Total) AS SumTotal
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(dbo.OrderLineItems.Quantity * dbo.Products.ItemPrice) AS Total,
          dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate AS OrderDate
   FROM dbo.OrderLineItems
   INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID
   INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersTbl ON dbo.OrderLineItems.ItemID = dbo.OrdersTbl.ItemID
   WHERE (dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-31 00:00:00')
   GROUP BY dbo.OrdersTbl.OrderDate) As T
```

This would work, but I don't think this a good one to work with lots of data, If you could post the table structure, may be it would be easy for everyone.

Comment: You have an alias with a dot in it.

Comment: that would probably help, i uploaded a link to my table structure.

Comment: Besides throwing a syntax error for the outer level (due to a column not in an aggregate/`GROUP BY` clause), the `SUM(SUM(...))` would reduce to just a regular `SUM(...)`.  And I think the OP wants both per-date and the overall total.